# Need to install Ruby 1.9.3 on Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, bash, installation, rvm, ruby-1.9.3

I had Ruby 1.9.3 running on Mac OS X Lion (I had to use RVM because normal home brew install didn't work) and then installing Mountain Lion (or its subsequent update) has caused Ruby 1.9.3 to no longer be installed + all gems have been uninstalled and I'm back on Ruby 1.8.7

I have the latest XCode version (4.4.1) installed and I've tried multiple different suggestions from similar StackOverflow questions with no success.

What I want is a fresh start (if possible), I would like advice for how to completely uninstall any crap I've installed to do with Ruby and RVM and to start again! Then maybe I can get assistance with installing Ruby 1.9.3

But I can give you an idea of what I'm doing at the moment which is failing...

- Executing `ruby -v` results in `ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]`
- Executing `rvm -v` results in `rvm 1.15.7 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]`
- Executing `brew upgrade ruby` results in: http://pastebin.com/KetSau7k
- Executing `rvm install 1.9.3` results in: http://pastebin.com/8YKg4wXb - which when I then press `q` to exit it continues to try and install and fails...

Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/markmcdonnell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /Users/markmcdonnell/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configuring 
Error running ' ./configure --prefix=/Users/markmcdonnell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/markmcdonnell/.rvm/usr ', please read /Users/markmcdonnell/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

- I've also tried `rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang` but after an initial message you've seen already (where I press `q` to quit the message and continue with an install) it then tells me `You requested building with 'clang' but it is not in your path.`

There's also a number of other things I've installed and commands I've executed to try and get this blasted Ruby 1.9.3 to install but none of it has worked - hence why I think I might need to start from scratch (if possible?).

Any help getting this installed (and a bit of a clean-up too) along with an explanation for someone who isn't very Bash/CLI minded would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: This question might get more attention when posted on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Do you have the command line tools for xcode insalled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer actually came from @kitcambridge (on twitter) he suggested that although I had the latest XCode downloaded I needed to open XCode and then into its preferences area and look for the 'download' tab where I could then download the 'Command Line Tools' which when installed fixed some of the issues such as missing libraries/links.

This worked for me. But if it didn't then I think the next best solution would have been to try the Rails installer as suggested by @mpapis - although I don't build Rail applications it still seemed like a good solution.

Comment: Just to confirm, downloading "Command Line Tools" in Xcode worked for me too.

Answer (score 3):

the easiest way to get ruby (and rails) is to use http://railsinstaller.org - it will install all required libraries and ruby (with rvm).

also there is new option in RVM to install binary rubies:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 --binary
```

it might show you list of missing libraries - you need to install them and try again.

full list of binary rubies is available here: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/config/remote

Answer (score 0):

You may want to keep a eye of tokaido by Yehuda Katz which is a binary installer for OSX that he is working on.  There is allot more to it then just that and probably best to read about it here http://yehudakatz.com/2012/04/13/tokaido-my-hopes-and-dreams/ and the github repo is here
https://github.com/tokaido/tokaidoapp#readme